# Crontab no error but doesn't execute script

Tags: freebsd, cron

I'm trying to execute a shell script from cron on Freebsd.

To test whether `crontab` is working at all, I wrote the line

```
  * * * * * echo "Hello" > /home/myuser/logile
```

and it work fine.

But when trying to execute any script it doesn't do anything, not even an error. (In the script I tried to run is just the same echo command)
Below is the output of `crontab -l`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh  
PATH=/etc:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin  
HOME=/home/myuser  
MAILTO=myuser  
* * * * * /home/myuser/shellscript.sh > /home/myuser/logfile
```

Why is the script not getting executed, although `crontab` is obviously running?
Permission for all files are set to `rwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: Could you post the script? I know you said it's trivial... but... :P

Comment: the script is:  
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello"

and works from interaktive shell ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/myuser/shellscript.sh
```

or

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/myuser/shellscript.sh
```

worked for me in Macosx 10.6 as rootuser

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked that the command line has a linefeed/CR at the end of the line? I struggled for hours trying to find a reason for non-executing php script on cron when I simply hadn't pressed enter at the end of the line when I edited the cron jobs with crontab -e :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for this info. Pressing enter at the end of the line solved the problem for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked `/var/log/cron` for clues?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/myuser/shellscript.sh > /home/myuser/logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

cron sends any errors via email to owner of the crontab file (often "root" so you might check that account's email).  To have any errors mailed to "crontabOnFreebsd" put:

```
MAILTO=crontabOnFreebsd
```

in your crontab (near the top).

For more info issue this command:

```
man 5 crontab
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error, then your logfile might not capture it, try this:

```
* * * * * /home/myuser/shellscript.sh > /home/myuser/logfile 2> /home/myuser/errorfile
```

Its been a while since I did any cron stuff; but things that always used to get me:

1. Environment variables not been set: generally I found it necessary to set up full paths (even to things like 'cat') to all commands [or at least set ENV variables within the script itself].
2. Ensure the user who owns the script etc is really the user which is running the script: this might not be the same user when you test from the interactive shell. Same goes for the directories/files that the script might write to.
3. Also: check the email for the root user - you might find that the errors have been diverted to the inbox, which may help you troubleshoot this further.